# calculating the point of acceleration

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, physics, accelerator

I've been struggling to calculate the accelerator. I've spend a whole day in searching, trial & error but all in vain. I've one horizontal line on the stage (AS3) of let say 200 width. Center-point of that line is on 60 (if it was 100, I would have surely done it by just calculating the percentage). Now I need to know the width of given percentage. For example, total width of 60% or where will 30% (or any other percentage) start from?

What I know is the total width, and the center-point (either in percentage or in width).

Your help will be highly appreciated. In case if there is any formula, please give me details, don't just mention a/b/c as I'd never been a student of physics :(

Edit:

I don't have 10 reputations, so I can't post image directly here. Please click the following link to see the image.

Link: http://oi62.tinypic.com/11sk183.jpg

[image: example]

Edit:

Here is what I want exactly: I want to travel n% from any point (A/B/C/D) to its relative point (A->B/A->D ...) (Link)
http://i59.tinypic.com/2wp2lbl.jpg

Comment: Can you add a diagram or a link to what you are describing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a non-linear scale, so that pixel 1 on the line is 0%, pixel 100 on the line is 60% and pixel 200 is 100%?

If x=pixelpos/200 is the relative position on the line, one easy variation of the linear scale y=x*100% is y=(x+a*x*(1-x))*100%.

For x=0.5 the value is y=0.5+a*0.25, so for that to be 0.6=60% one needs a=0.4.

To get in the reverse direction the x for y=0.3=30%, one needs to solve a quadratic equation y=x*(1+a*(1-x)) or a*x^2-(1+a)*x+y=0. With the general solution formula, this gives

```
x = (1+a)/(2*a)-sqrt((1+a)^2-4*a*y)/(2*a)
  = (2*y) / ( (1+a) + sqrt((1+a)^2-4*a*y) )
  = (2*y) / ( (1+a) + sqrt((1-a)^2+4*a*(1-y)) )
```

and with a=0.4 and y=0.3

```
x = 0.6/( 1.4 + sqrt(1.98-0.48) )
approx 0.6/2.6=3/13=231/1001 approx 0.23
```

corresponding to pixel 46.

This will **only** work for a between -1 and 1, since for other values the slope at x=0 or x=1 will not be positive.

---

**Another** simple formula uses hyperbola instead of parabola,

```
y=a*x/(1+(a-1)*x)
```

with the inversion by

```
y+(a-1)*x*y = a*x  <=>  y = (a-(a-1)*y)*x
x = (y/a)/(1+(1/a-1)*y)
```

and

```
a = (y*(1-x))/(x*(1-y))
```

here there is no problem with monotonicity as long as there is no pole for x in [0,1], which is guaranteed for a>0.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I can properly set the value of 'a'. However, when I use the equation -you provided-, after 50%, value of sqrt goes in negative. Also before 50% it gives wrong values. Thanks for your help, I even can't +1 as of now...

but it just does not solve my problem :( I'm still trying hard to figure it out, I've been trying for the last few hours now! can u help plz calculate it for me?

x = 0.29375450149192306 (it is rational value, it should be 50%)
a = 0.9941324619630223 (to make y = 0.5)

how can i now get the value of 80% for example?

Comment: The usefulness of the quadratic formula is rather restricted to be close to the diagonal. I added the class of hyperbolic functions that should give full flexibility for shifting the 50% point. Other shapes are possible, but not so simple. You would have to exactly specify the expected behavior.

Comment: hi LutzL, thanks for the reply again. I was so busy on something else so I could not come online. Here is what I want exactly: [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/2wp2lbl.jpg)
Note that this is 2D image, my app is not 3D, top-view is for reference only. Now I want to travel 70% from B to C, or travel 90% from A to D and so on... so how can I calculate it? U probably wont believe but I've literally spent 4 days! I method I found was to get the vanishing points, but that would give me 50% only (and i even don't know the equation to calculate vanishing points)... so can u help me out??

Comment: What is the situation on the model side? Do you have the 3D coordinates of the points available? The points between A and B are (1-x)*A+x*B, where the distance is x*100% in 3D, but not in the projection. To translate distance ratios in the projection back into 3D distances is a little more complicated, but can be done. Read also about "cross ratios", they are closely related to this topic.